# CSS: Hide box-shadow only when div is getting overflowed

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Final Edit**: I managed to do it. I created a variable to remember the root in which I am currently. And in the Navigation page code, I used a v-bind with a conditional argument. I also moved the box shadow code from the style section to the HTML section to use it inside the v-bind. Thanks for the help.

I have a navigation bar with a box shadow. My navigation bar is visible on every page of my website. However, on my Home page, I have a hero section overflowing the Navigation bar. I want the box shadow to disappear there.

[Navigation bar on the home page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlqwC.png)

[Navigation bar everywhere else](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wu5V8.png)

I tried to give a higher z-index to the content of the Navigation bar but it did not work. If someone could help me out I would be very grateful.

Part of the code for my navigation bar:

```
header {
    background-color: transparent;
    padding: 0 25px;
    z-index: 1;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 6px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 2px 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);


    .link {
        font-weight: 500;
        font-size: 14px;
        padding: 0 2px;
        transition: 0.3s color ease;
        z-index: 110;
        &:hover {
            color: #1eb8b8;
        }
    }
}
```

Part of the code for my hero section:

```
.hero-section {
  z-index: 100;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-image: url(../assets/hero.jpg);
  margin-top: -145px;
  height: 115vh;
  width: 100%; 
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Edit:
**The hero section and the navigation bar are in 2 different files**
This is the HTML part of the code for the Navigation bar:

```
<header>
    <nav class="container">
        <div class="nav-links">
            <ul v-show="!mobile">
                <router-link class="link" :to="{name: 'Home'}">Home</router-link>
                <router-link class="link" :to="{name: 'Prints'}">Prints</router-link>
                <router-link class="link" :to="{name: 'Blogs'}">Blogs</router-link>
```

*The links are below the header section so I think that is why the z-index method is not working*

For the hero section:

```
<div class="home">
    <div class="hero-section">
      <h2>Welcome to my website!</h2>
    </div>
```

Comment: We need to see the HTML too, z-index affects the order inside the current [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context)

Answer (score 0):

For `z-index` to take effect you'll need to apply a `position` to the elements you want to give a `z-index`, like so:

```
.link {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 110;
}
```

In short, "z-index" only applies to positioned elements. Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

Comment: I tried this, but I think that since the z-index of my links is included in the header it does not work. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand what you're trying to achieve but it sounds like it might not have anything to do with z-index. If you're wanting to hide the box shadow on your nav page when on your home page then would it not be simpler to just apply a class on the homepage that removes the box-shadow?

Answer (score 0):

If your header is the Navigation bar
Do increase the z index of that element.
The higher your z index value is, your element appears on top of stack.
Learn more here > https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/the-z-index-css-property-a-comprehensive-look/

Edit:
position is very important as suggested by @Joe Spurling

Comment: Yes, but if the whole navigation bar has a higher z-index, the box shadow will also be visible. My goal is only to hide the box shadow when it is getting overflowed by the hero section.

Answer (score 0):

box-shadow: none  or also you can write box-shadow: unset

&:hover{
box-shadow: unset
}

Comment: Thank you for the advice! But in my situation I would like the box-shadow to disapear not only when I put my mouse over it, but most importantly when the hero section is overflowing on it. In other words, want to box-shading to be removed from my home page.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).